# REPLACE 2 string with replacement string in sql

Tags: sql

```
SSN=LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(A.SSN,'-','')))
```

Can some one please help me? This code replaces "-" with '' of ssn column which works. But now I want to also replace dots `.` with `''` string. Can someone help me how to replace both `-` and `.`?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one more `replace`

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(A.SSN,'-',''),'.','')))
```

If you are using Oracle, the easiest way to do this is using `regexp_replace` to only get the digits.

```
regexp_replace(ssn, '\D', '')
```